# How to query for the occurrence of an element in the array in mongo DB aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

> I'm using mongoose to connect to Mongo DB.

At first this is my schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TestSchema = new Schema({
  story: String,
  seenByUser: [String],
  medicationStage: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      "no-medication",
      "just-after-medication",
      "towards-end-of-medication",
    ],
    required: true,
  },
});

// Compile model from schema
const TestModel = mongoose.model("Test", TestSchema);

module.exports = {
  Test: TestModel,
};
```

Here you can see I have a field called `seenByUser` which is an array of strings that is an array of user names. I'm setting up a data aggregation pipeline where I want to see given a user name **fetch me all the documents where this user Name** *does not occur* **in `seenByUser` array. grouped by `medicationStage`**. I'm unable to create this pipeline. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've undesrtood correctly you can try this aggregation:

- First `$match` where does not exists `yourValue` into the array `seenByUser`.
- Then `$group` by `medicationStage`. This create a nested array (because `$push` add the whole array)
- And `$project` to use `$reduce` and flat the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "seenByUser": {
      "$ne": yourValue
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$medicationStage",
    "seenByUser": {
      "$push": "$seenByUser"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "medicationStage": "$_id",
    "seenByUser": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$seenByUser",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$$value",
            "$$this"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TdRhivYcJmZ)